# Dax Code with dynamic selected filter date

Tags: powerbi, dax

PBI Newbie here! Need help on how to formulate the dax code on how to measure with coded calendar in the Table data from Jan 1 2021 to Aug 15, 2023. Thank you for the help

Scenario
Dashboard Dynamic Filter Date: Current Filter at 2023 until July 31, 2023

MeasureDax needed: Count all the data from Jan 1 2021 until july 31, 2023 ( or depends on what the selected filter but it counts starting from minimum date available in the data (e.a Jan 1 2021 until the current selected filter date)

Outcome: 5

Or

Dashboard Dynamic Filter Date: Current Filter at 2023 until Aug 15, 2023
Outcome: 6

Data:

```
|Code |  Set Up Complete Date|
|10537| 02/01/2021|
|10542| 26/04/2021|
|10543| 25/03/2022|
|10568| 26/05/2022|
|12176| 31/07/2023|
|12177| 15/08/2023|
```

Scenario
Dashboard Dynamic Filter Date: Current Filter at 2023 until July 31, 2023

MeasureDax needed: Count all the data from Jan 1 2021 until july 31, 2023 ( or depends on what the selected filter but it counts starting from minimum date available in the data (e.a Jan 1 2021 until the current selected filter date)

Outcome: 5

Or

Dashboard Dynamic Filter Date: Current Filter at 2023 until Aug 15, 2023
Outcome: 6

Answer (score 0):

If the time intelligence is on with your "Set Up Complete Date"
You can [count the rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/countrows-function-dax) available in your table filtered by your slicers